# Reading From Firebase for Only Current User - Android

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am having trouble with reading data for only the current user logged into my system. At the moment, it is reading every users data for "team" into the listView.

For context, this is a sports app, where the names of the team are read into a listView.

Here is my code:

```java
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    ArrayList<Object> array = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.i("snap", "onDataChange: " + dataSnapshot.getValue());

        for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String userId = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            String idKey = ds.getKey();
            for(DataSnapshot team: ds.getChildren()) {
                String key = team.getKey();
                Log.i("my team", team.toString());
                array.add(key);
            }
        }
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(StatisticsActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
        listViewTeam.setAdapter(adapter);
        dataSnapshot.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

If anyone can help with this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Fixed formatting and added code syntax highlighting.

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Answer (score 0):

See the code with comments

```
//get firebase user id as you did before
    String userId = firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    //get reference and put there the name of the table where you have users
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(USERS_TABLE).child(userId);


    //grab info
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           //and here you receive the logged in user
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```